# Matrix of a linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

In $\mathbb{R^3}$ we consider the following vectors $v_1 = (1,0,1), v_2=(-2,2,1), v_3=(0,1,1)$

Let $V$ be a vector space , $V=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3}\mid x+y-z=0\}.$

Let $W = \operatorname{span}(v_2)$.

$B =\{ (v_1,v_3)\}$ is a basis for $V$

Let $P$ be the projection on $V$ parallel to $W$.

Determine the matrix of $P$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R^3}$ and $B$.

The problem is I've only dealt so far with determining matrices where they give out the linear transformation such that $f(x,y,z)=f(x+2y,x+y+z)$. And I'm clueless on how to approach this question.

Hints and advice are appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't understand the problem, V is a plane and $v_2$ how can a projection on V be parallel to $v_2$?

Comment: I've been trying to figure that out , that's litreally what the problem says though.

Comment: It seems completely meaningless to me, by the way maybe someone else can give an advice.

Comment: Isn't it possible to project any $v = (x,y,z)$ onto a plane in a direction which is parallel to $v_2$ , I have a fuzzy idea about this too.

Comment: @gimusi It means that $W$ is the kernel of the projection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

find $P$ such that $v_2$ is in the kernel of $P.$ $v_1, v_3$ are the column space of $P.$

In the basis $B, P = \begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

In the standard basis.

$P = \begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0\\0&2&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&0\\0&2&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$

$\begin{bmatrix}-1&-2&2\\2&3&-2\\1&1&0\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: How do you deal with the request "Let $P$ be the projection on $V$ parallel to $W$"?

Comment: With some combinations $v_1, v_3$ as column space of $P$ we are projecting onto the space $V$.   With $v_2$ is in the kernel of $P$ then any vector (or vector components) in the direction of $v_2$ get flattened. i.e. any vector in $\mathbb R^{3}$ is translated parallel to $v_2$ until it finds it projection on the plane.

Comment: What are A and T ? And i'm still not quite sure i understand why is v2 in the kernel of P , I would be grateful if you can explain further , thanks.

Comment: Sorry, about the $A, T$ I changed the name of my variables as I was working on this, and didn't clean up.  Then I re-read the question and saw that you had called this matrix $P$ and changed them again.  If all vectors project parallel to $v_2$ then where does $v_2$ go?

Comment: Just to be sure , in 3-dimensional space $V$ represents a plane whereas $W$ represents a line , so we want to project our vector onto the plane $V$ in a direction parallel to the line $W$,Is this correct http://prntscr.com/hwm5xx ? Sorry for my bad drawing.

Comment: @Raku that is the idea.

Comment: One more thing , shouldn't it be $v_1$ and $v_3$ which are in the column space instead of  $v_1$ and $v_2$

Comment: Yes, I must have been tired yesterday!

Answer (score 1):

The concept of projection to V  parallel to W is easily understandable if one digs into  the geometric (or optics) etymology of the word *projection*.

We have seen powerpoint projectors sending images to a screen on the wall.
 Instead imagine a screen where parallel beam of light from the sun  (from a source at infinity as physicists  describe) fall onto a screen casting shadows of objects on its way.

A dot (which light cannot penetrate) occupying a position $v\in \mathbf{R}^3$ casts a shadow at a position $p(v)$ in the plane (of the screen).

Now remember sun's position is not fixed so the beam of light can be in any direction, not necessarily falling perpendicular to the screen.

So that is what a projection is: it is specified by  a target plane and a direction of approach towards that screen. Well it is a special kind of projection a $3\times3$ matrix of rank 2 satisfying $P^2=P$.

In general algebraically a projection in a vector space $V$ has a target space $V_1\subset V$ and a "direction subspace" $V_2\subset V$ which are complements of each other (that is they together span the whole space, and have just the zero vector in common).
So any vector $v\in V$ has a unique decomposition $v=v_1+v_2$ with $v_1\in V_1,\ v_2\in V_2$. The corresponding projection is $p(v) = v_1$.

That is all vectors in the direction subspace form the kernel, and for all vectors in the target space the projection does nothing (acts as identity on them).